Delete all where DOES NOT contain
I have this JSON file json1.json:
{
    "a":"val1",
    "b":"val2",
    "nest1": {
        "z": "x",
        "test": "containval"
    }
}

I need to get a new json where elements whose values that contain val are removed, ANY property can have val, this gets me close:
jq 'del(.. | select(. == "val1"))' .\json1.json

it produces this:
{
  "b": "val2",
  "nest1": {
    "z": "x",
    "test": "containval"
  }
}

Except that it checks for values being EQUAL to val1, and I only need where the value DOES NOT CONTAIN "val".
Desired output:
{
    "a":"val1",
    "b":"val2",
    "nest1": {
        "test": "containval"
    }
}


Why the downvotes? What can I do to improve the question I am asking? thanks for your feedback.

You are almost there. Instead of checking for equality, use the filters strings and contains() to select and remove the values that contain "val" (together with their associated keys).

The solution is simple. Instead of checking for equality, use the filters strings and contains() to select and remove the values that contain "val" (together with their associated keys):
del(.. | select(strings | contains("val")))

Check it online.

Please clean up your duplicating comment.

You were close. This should work:
del(.. | strings | select(index("val") | not))

